# Use Applescript to check if screen is locked on a Mac with Apple silicon?

Tags: mac, applescript, screen-lock, sonoma

For years, I've used Applescripts to check if my Mac's monitor is locked (not to be confused with checking if the screen saver is active.  I don't have the screen saver lock the screen since I use the screen saver as a giant clock when I'm home and I lock the screen when I leave).

Either the switch to Apple silicon or a Mac OS update has stopped scripts like this from checking if the screen is locked:

```
set isScreenLocked to do shell script "pmset -g ps | awk 'NR==2{print $2}'"
```

Scripts like this don't seem to work on Apple silicon either:

```
set isScreenLocked to do shell script "ioreg -n IODisplayWrangler | grep -i IOPowerManagement"
```

I'm running Mac OS Sonoma on an M1 Mac studio.  How can I use Applescript to check whether or not the screen is locked (again, not to be confused with the screen saver being active)?

Comment: What do you expect the output of `pmset -g ps` to be, when locked? The `man` page says that displays the battery status. (Also, I'm curious: what does the script *do* when the screen is locked?)

Comment: The script is for home automation stuff.  When the monitor isn't locked, it locks it.  When the monitor is locked, it tells other smart devices in my home to not do certain things.